# Azure VM Customscript not Downloading

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using below terraform .tf file . Its always showing the error as

> DownloadFileAsync: Error in downloading file from
>   https://github.dxc.com/raw/gist/jmathews4/2095e2436571715f94e05e5ac5400a67/raw/f554d018ae4fee12979b2ee6f5ac4abb3ff509aa/Terraform.ps1?token=AAAMrnoBPpBc7C8kN2_haQueWaqDhth-ks5bUGqhwA%3D%3D,
>   retry count 25, exception: System.Net.WebException: The request was
>   aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)

Any idea what could be issue with GIT?

```html
provider "azurerm" {
   
}

variable "location" { default = "Southeast Asia" }
variable "resourceGroup" { default = "TerraformResearchResourceGroup" }
variable "virtualMachine" { default = "terraformrvm" }

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ext" {
  name                 = "eagpocvmexxt"
  location             = "Southeast Asia"
  resource_group_name  = "terraformrg"
  virtual_machine_name = "terraformvm"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.8"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["https://github.dxc.com/raw/gist/jmathews4/2095e2436571715f94e05e5ac5400a67/raw/f554d018ae4fee12979b2ee6f5ac4abb3ff509aa/Terraform.ps1?token=AAAMrnoBPpBc7C8kN2_haQueWaqDhth-ks5bUGqhwA%3D%3D"],
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File Terraform.ps1"
    }
 SETTINGS

  tags {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the issue is Git is enforcing TLS 1.2 and extension doesnt like that, your workaround is to put the file somewhere where extension can download it without intervention. Azure Storage.

Comment: all-right. Any link telling about extension update roadmaps incorporating this TLS1.2 ?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, but looking at the error its using system.web so it either needs to modify how its using it or wait for it to upgrade, which probably wont happen soon